# vgxset command: Q parameter for resulting model object?

Tags: matlab, time-series

Matlab's command for defining a vector time series model is vgxset, the formalism for which can be accessed by the command "doc vgxset".  It says that the model parameter Q is "[a]n n-by-n symmetric innovations covariance matrix".  No description of what it is for.  I assumed that it was the covariance of the noise sources that show up in the equations for each times series in the archetypal representation of a vector time series, e.g., http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/time_series_book.pdf.

I could be off about something (I often am), but this doesn't seem to match results from actually issuing the command to estimate a model's parameters.  You can access the code that illustrates such estimation via the command "doc vgxvarx":

```
load Data_VARMA22
[EstSpec, EstStdErrors] = vgxvarx(vgxar(Spec), Y, [], Y0);
```

The object EstSpec contains the model, and the Q matrix is:

```
0.0518  0.0071
0.0071  0.0286
```

I would have expected that a covariance matrix as ones on the diagonal.  Obviously, I misunderstand and/or mis-guessed at the purpose of Q.  However, if you actually pull up the code for vgxset ("edit vgxset"), the comments explicitly describe Q as an "[i]nnovations covariance matrix".

I have 3 questions:

(1) What exactly is Q?

(2)Is there a Matlab reference document that I've failed to locate for fundamental parameters like this?

(3)If it isn't the covariance matrix for the noise sources, how does one actually supply actual noise source covariances to the model?

Please note that this question is specifically about Matlab's command for setting up the model, and as such, does not belong in the more concept-oriented Cross Validated Stack Exchange forum.  I have posted this to:

(1) [vgxset command: Q parameter for resulting model object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444944/vgxset-command-q-parameter-for-resulting-model-object)

(2) http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/tg59h1wkRCw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to `iterate` to an answer, but being so many branches of discussion, i prefer to access directly onto this format. Whatever mean, this is a constructive process, as the purpose of this forum is...

Some previous "clarifications":

1. The Output Covariance from `EstSpec.Q` *after* and *before* running the command `vgxvarx` are quite similar. Thus the command is outputting what he is shiningly expecting from itself.
2. As an Output Covariance -or whatever other meaning for the `Q` parameter- is almost never to be a "mask" of the parameters to use, -i.e. an identity or a sparse zero-one matrix input parameter-. If you can assign it as a diagonal multiplied by some scalar univariate scalar is a different history. This is a covariance, plainly, just as in other `MATLAB` commands.

Hence:

**(2) Is there a Matlab reference document that I've failed to locate for fundamental parameters like this?**

No, Matlab ussualy don't give further explanations for "non popular" commands. Yes, this is, under some measure, "not popular", so i would not be impressed if the answer for this question is no.

Of course, the doctoral method is to check the provided references, on this case, those provided under `doc vartovec`. Which i dunno the hell where to find without order the books seeking the proper library or seeking the overall internet on five minutes...

Thus the obscure method is always better... check the code for the function by doing `edit vgxvarx`. Check the commented Section `% Step 7 - Solve for parameters` (Line 515, Matlab R2014b). There are calculations for a `Q` matrix through a function `mvregress`. At this point, both of us know, this is the core function.

This `mvregress` function (Line 62, Matlab R2014b) receives an input parameter called `Covar0`, which is described as a `*D-by-D matrix to be used as the initial estimate for SIGMA*`.

This antecedent leads to the answer for (1).

**(1) What exactly is Q?**

The `MATLAB` code has dozens of switch -both as options and auto-triggered- so i am actually not sure of which algorithm are you interested on, or based on your data, which ones are actually "triggered" :). Please read the previous answer, and place a Debug Point on the `mvregress` function:

```
Covar=Covar+CovAdj;  %Line 433, Matlab R2014b
```

and/or at:

```
Covar = (Covar + Resid'*Resid) / Count; % Line 439, Matlab R2014b
```

Having that, the *exact meaning* of `Q`, and as indicated by the `mvregress` help, would be an "**Initial Matrix for the Estimate of the Output Covariance Matrix**". The average is simply given by averaging the `Count`s...

*But*, for the provided data, making:

```
Spec.Q=[1 0.1;0.1 1];
```

and then running `vgxvarx`, the parameter `Covar` never got initialized!. 
Which for the presented unfortunate case, leads to a simply "**Unused Parameter**".

**(3) If it isn't the covariance matrix for the noise sources, how does one actually supply actual noise source covariances to the model?**

I've lost tons of manhours trying to gather the correct information from pre-built `Matlab` commands. Thus, my suggestion here, is to stick onto the concepts of system identification, and I would put my faith under one of the following alternatives:

1. Keep believing, and dig a bit and debug inside the `mvregress` function, and check if some of the `EstMethod`s -i.e. `cwls` `ecm` `mvn` under Line 195- leads to a proper filling of the `Covar0` parameter,
2. Stick to the `vgxvarx` command, but let the `Q` parameter go, and diagonalize | normalize the data properly, in order to let the algorithm identify the data as a Identically Distributed Gaussian Noise,
3. Send `vgxvarx` to the hell, and use `arx`. I am not sure about the current stability of `vgxvarx`, but i am quite sure `arx` should be more "stable" on this regard...

Good Luck,

hypfco.

**EDIT**

A huge and comprehensive comment, i have nothing much to add.

1. Indeed, it is quite probable the `vgxvarx` was run on the Matlab data sample. Hence the results lay explained,
2. I tried to *use* the `Q` parameter on the `vgxvarx`, with no success by now. If any working code is found, it would be interesting to include it,
3. The implementation of the noise transformation over the data should be really simple, of the form:

   `Y1=(Y-Y0)*L`

with `L` the left triangular cholesky for the inverse calculated covariance of `Y`, and `Y0` the mean,

4. I think the `MA` part is as critical as the `AR` part. Unless you have very good reasons, you usually cannot say you explained your data in a gaussian way.
5. From your very last comment, I really suggest you to move onto a better, more established command for doing `AR`, `MA`, `ARMA` and such flavours. I am pretty sure they handle the MV case...
6. Again, `Matlab` don't impress me on that behaviour...

Cheers...

hypfco

Comment: You found EstSpec.Q to be similar before and after running vgxvarx; I found them to be identical, so I thought that vgxvarx was run before the data file was created.  From your response, however, Q might be both an input and an output (i.e., it is updated in the estimation process).  It'll take me a bit more time to follow through with the code execution tracking, but thanks for the suggestions of how to go about it.  (I find it disturbing that the result of this tracking could be, as you say, "Unused Parameter").

Comment: I understand what you suggest about becoming a "doctor" and delving into the academic literature to figure out what is likely being done in these functions (though I'm not sure how vartovec ties into vgxvarx).  Unfortunately, I'm not doing a doctoral in time series, and my timelines are much shorter.  The expectations are to get a rough picture using the methods which can be understood and applied in a fixed amount of time.

Comment: Having said that, however, I've spent a great number of weeks completely immersed in background reading.  Nevertheless, the modelling is not being done in an academic context, and the aim is not to push (or even to necessarily approach) the boundaries of knowledge.  My challenge now is to take a the limited amount of acquired knowledge and see how it can be beneficially applied.  Of course it's tricky because you don't know what you don't know.  Notwithstanding this priority, I'm still waiting for papers and books to arrive.

Comment: I appreciate the 3 ways ahead as you have summarized them.  Some are more palatable than others at this point in time.  For example, I'm not sure I can "let the Q parameter go" at this particular because I'm only at the stage of trying to understand the solution process.  So I should at least be able to read and understand the help pages for the commands in order to be able to follow the Matlab time series tutorials.

Comment: At that point, I think I can make judicious transformations like what you suggest.  The Cochrane reference has some examples of transforming coupled noise sources, and hopefully, I will see implementation examples in the tutorials.

So once again, thank you for your in-depth answer.  I'd like to keep this question open for a while longer in case someone else can chime in with his/her perspective.

Comment: By the way, I was wrong about covariance matrix having ones on the diagonal.  That's a cross-correlation matrix.  I also found that the Q values roughly match the covariances of the noise that was used in generating the Y-vaues.  Furthermore, the estimation command in my original post used an VAR approximation to the underlying VARMA model, which could explain the discepancy between Q-values and actual covariances.

Comment: PS. Regarding using ARX instead of vgxvarx, I expect to need multivariate at some point, though it may be a VAR (not sure if VARMA is necessary).  I have yet to form a "map" of all the classes for time series, but my impression was that the core class was vgxset for vector time series, and vgxvarx is an estimation function for the parameters.

Comment: Just to rub salt in it, I am now clear on the significance of vgxset's caveat: "vgxvarx...ignores MAsolve".  So even though it deals with VARMAX model specification, vector moving averages is not supported.  Now I also appreciate the significance of your mention of vartovec.  It's not quite a VMA, though, and I've never seen such "error correction" in the time series texts/papers/tutorials that I've browsed.  I initially dismissed it as something very specific to digital signal processing in communications.

Comment: Matlab really *should* state at the *top* of its vgxset document that MA is not supported.  Right up where it self-describes as having to do with VARMAX models, *not* down below after all the parameters have been described.

Comment: Ummmm.... Did you said the magic word ARMA?.... I am not sure if these implementations are quite flexible, even for the commands i ussualy handle. When using noise models, i ussualy have inputs, and then i switch onto the State Space representation... By the way, how many variables are you handling, and what is the represented process?...

Comment: Well, I meant VARMA...but I was corrected on my last comment.  vgxvarx may not support moving averages, but it is possible that vgxpred, vgxsim, and vgxproc do.  I have to plough through all the tutorials to get a big picture view.  I wish there was a big picture document to give the lay of the land in terms of toolbox functionality, including unsupported areas.  It would certainly prevent misinterpretations of caveats such as the one for vgxset that I cited.  As for my model, I have 3 potential analyses, and I have to take stock of the method and engage the people for data availability.

Comment: In other words, I need to build the airplane as it is flying, and the one piece I have control over is familiarization with the pros/cons and requirements of the method (limited by time!).  The data...discussions on that will occur.

Comment: Aw... this is a system them... I would try a dynamical model then... those AR, MA, ARMA are better for finance phenomena, where no clear input is... Whatever, it is your dish :).... Better finish your VAR* and go...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78928/discussion-between-user36800-and-hypfco).

Comment: I tried "automatically move this discussion to chat" as suggested, but our firewall apparently permit this.

Comment: Hypfco, I appreciate your edit (I didn't notice it yesterday).  I'm going to plough through the vector model tutorials before delving into the matrix inner workings.  I may try the non-vector models after, since they seem to support vectorized.  As I mentiond, howver, vgx*'s restriction to AR only seems to apply to estimation of model parameters.  I haven't yet figured out the value added of vgxset type models for my situation; tutorial shows that AR can approximate ARMA.